# unable to spin up instances having flavor greater than m1.tiny

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am unable to spin up instances having flavor greater than m1.tiny on a server having 64GB RAM. The error reported by horizon is "Volume 71bc03cf-6ab1-4511-8763-43647fd1ea2c did not finish being created even after we waited 0 seconds or 1 attempts." However, there are no errors with ,m1.tiny. I am using stable/ocata on Ubuntu 16.04. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Local.conf:

```
[[local|localrc]]
HOST_IP=10.0.0.150 
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
RABBIT_PASSWORD=password
SERVICE_TOKEN=password
SERVICE_PASSWORD=password
ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
enable_plugin zun https://git.openstack.org/openstack/zun
enable_plugin zun-tempest-plugin https://git.openstack.org/openstack/zun-tempest-plugin
RECLONE=yes
#This below plugin enables installation of container engine on Devstack.
#The default container engine is Docker
enable_plugin devstack-plugin-container https://git.openstack.org/openstack/devstack-plugin-container
SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen
LOG_COLOR=false
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
VERBOSE=True

KURYR_CAPABILITY_SCOPE=local
KURYR_ETCD_PORT=2379
enable_plugin kuryr-libnetwork https://git.openstack.org/openstack/kuryr-libnetwork

ENABLE_IDENTITY_V2=False

LIBS_FROM_GIT="python-zunclient"


enable_plugin zun-ui https://github.com/openstack/zun-ui

enable_plugin heat https://git.openstack.org/openstack/heat
```

Comment: Off-topic; https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/109842

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed by following this [link](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/109842/devstack-fails-instance-creation-other-than-tiny/).